# Java8 Adding Hours To LocalDateTime Not Working

Tags: java-8, java-time, hour

I tried like below, but in both cases, it is showing the same time. What am I doing wrong?

```
LocalDateTime currentTime = LocalDateTime.now(ZoneId.of("UTC"));
Instant instant = currentTime.toInstant(ZoneOffset.UTC);
Date currentDate = Date.from(instant);
System.out.println("Current Date = " + currentDate);

currentTime.plusHours(12);
Instant instant2 = currentTime.toInstant(ZoneOffset.UTC);
Date expiryDate = Date.from(instant2);
System.out.println("After 12 Hours = " + expiryDate);
```

"Current Date" Time is showing the same as "After 12 Hours"...

Answer (score 51, accepted):

The documentation of `LocalDateTime` specifies the instance of `LocalDateTime` is immutable, for example [`plusHours`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html#plusHours-long-)

> `public LocalDateTime plusHours(long hours)`
>
> Returns a copy of this `LocalDateTime` with the specified number of
>   hours added.
>
> This instance is immutable and unaffected by this method call.
>
> **Parameters:**
>       `hours` - the hours to add, may be negative
>   **Returns:**
>       a LocalDateTime based on this date-time with the hours added, not null
>   **Throws:**
>       DateTimeException - if the result exceeds the supported date range

So, you create a new instance of `LocalDateTime` when you execute plus operation, you need to assign this value as follows:

```
LocalDateTime nextTime = currentTime.plusHours(12);
Instant instant2 = nextTime.toInstant(ZoneOffset.UTC);
Date expiryDate = Date.from(instant2);
System.out.println("After 12 Hours = " + expiryDate);
```

I hope it can be helpful for you.

Comment: Damn, i missed the immutable part. It works now. Thank You Very Much.

Answer (score 11):

From the `java.time` [package Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) (emphasis mine):

> The classes defined here represent the principal date-time concepts,
>   including instants, durations, dates, times, time-zones and periods.
>   They are based on the ISO calendar system, which is the de facto world
>   calendar following the proleptic Gregorian rules. **All the classes are
>   immutable and thread-safe.**

Since every class in the `java.time` package is immutable, you need to capture the result:

```
LocalDateTime after = currentTime.plusHours(12);
...
```

Answer (score 0):

This is simple, you can use

```
LocalDateTime's method "plusHours(numberOfHours)
```

Like This

```
localDateTime.plusHours(numberOfHours);
```