# Android Studio - Calculating finish time by adding hours to a set time

Tags: java, android, mobile

Hi I was wondering if there is any java code out there that would calculate an estimated finish time based on adding a certain amount of hours to a set time.

for example...

'dateButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.angry_btn);
        dateButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

```
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            LocalDateTime currentTime = LocalDateTime.now(ZoneId.of("UTC"));
            Instant instant = currentTime.toInstant(ZoneOffset.UTC);
            Date currentDate = Date.from(instant);
            dateButton.setText("Current Date = " + currentDate);


            LocalDateTime nextTime = currentTime.plusHours(12);
            Instant instant2 = nextTime.toInstant(ZoneOffset.UTC);
            Date expiryDate = Date.from(instant2);
            TextView endtime = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.endtimetextView);
            endtime.setText((CharSequence) expiryDate);
        }
    });'
```

User clicks a button called start which captures the current date and time, adds on a duration which has been entered by the user in a textbox e.g. 12 hours, then the end time is calculated and displayed in a textview below.

This is not working and also not allowing me to run on my device as the target SDK is too high.

Any help would be great.

thanks!

Comment: Which version of Java are you using? Java 8 and above have better support for manipulating dates and times. Take a look! https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html#package.description

Comment: i think its duplicated to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31003605/java8-adding-hours-to-localdatetime-not-working

Comment: Ive just tried doing it as a simple addition calculation but no luck and Daniel I tried that method and it has not worked either.

Answer (score 0):

Do not mix the old legacy date-time classes such as `java.util.Date` with the java.time classes. The java.time classes entirely supplant the legacy classes.

Do not use `LocalDateTime` when trying to represent actual moments on the time zone. The `Local…` classes have no concept of offset-from-UTC nor time zone.

The `Instant` class represents a moment in the timeline in UTC with a resolution of nanoseconds.

```
Instant instant = Instant.now() ;
```

Add twelve hours.

```
Instant later = instant.plusHours( 12 ) ;
```

View that moment through the lens of some particular region’s time zone.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Pacific/Auckland" ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = later.atZone( z ) ;
```

To generate a string representing this value using standard ISO 8601 format, call `toString`. For other formats, search Stack Overflow for `DateTimeFormatter` as this has already been covered many times.

Older Android lacks the java.time classes. See the ThreeTen-Backport and ThreeTenABP projects.